# Nested right cases

Tags: align, amsmath, arrays, cases

I was reading a script for maths and came across this "picture" and was wondering how he typeset it in LaTeX, so I wanted to try myself.

First I thought of cases, but that did not work as intended. Then I tried arrays but while trying to align the arrays with the top line but not getting larger curly braces than wanted I could not succeed.

I would like to get the centred look, or at least no manual spacing adding.

This is what the sources looks like:
[image: Source of what I want to recreate.]

My attempt:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{rcases}
            \begin{rcases}
                    \begin{rcases}
                        \text{ganz rational, Polynom:} \\[-1ex]
                        y = f(x) = x \\
                        \text{gebrochen rational:} \\[-1ex]
                        y = f(x) = \frac1x
                    \end{rcases}
                    \quad \text{rational} \quad \\
                \mskip220mu\text{irrational:} \\[-1ex]
                \mskip220mu y = f(x) = \sqrt{x}
            \end{rcases} \quad\text{algebraisch} \quad \\ 
        \mskip360mu\text{transzendent:} \\[-1ex]
        \mskip360mu y = f(x) = \sin x
    \end{rcases}\quad \text{elementar}
\end{equation}
```

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do with the package `cascade`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cascade,calc}

\begin{document}


\Cascade
  {}
  {
    \Cascade
      {}
      { 
        \ShortCascade
          {\begin{tabular}{c}ganz rational, Polynom:\\ $y=(x)=x$\end{tabular}}
          {\begin{tabular}{c}gebrochen rational:\\ $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$\end{tabular}}
        rational
      }
      {}
      {\begin{tabular}{c}irrational\\ $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$\end{tabular}}
    algebraisch
  }
  {}
  {\begin{tabular}{c}tranzendent\\ $y=f(x)=\sin x$\end{tabular}}
elemantar

\bigskip

\Cascade
  { 
    \Cascade
      { 
        \ShortCascade
          {\begin{tabular}{c}ganz rational, Polynom:\\ $y=(x)=x$\end{tabular}}
          {\begin{tabular}{c}gebrochen rational:\\ $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$\end{tabular}}
        rational
      }
      {}
      {}
      {\begin{tabular}{c}irrational\\ $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$\end{tabular}}
    algebraisch
  }
  {}
  {}
  {\begin{tabular}{c}tranzendent\\ $y=f(x)=\sin x$\end{tabular}}
elemantar

\vspace{1cm}

\Cascade
  {}
  {
    \Cascade
      {}
      { 
        \ShortCascade
          {\begin{tabular}{c}ganz rational, Polynom:\\ $y=(x)=x$\end{tabular}}
          {\begin{tabular}{c}gebrochen rational:\\ $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$\end{tabular}}
        \makebox[\widthof{$y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$}]{rational}
      }
      {}
      {\begin{tabular}{c}irrational\\ $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$\end{tabular}}
    \makebox[\widthof{$y=f(x)=\sin(x)$}]{algebraisch}
  }
  {}
  {\begin{tabular}{c}tranzendent\\ $y=f(x)=\sin x$\end{tabular}}
elemantar

\bigskip

\Cascade
  { 
    \Cascade
      { 
        \ShortCascade
          {\begin{tabular}{c}ganz rational, Polynom:\\ $y=(x)=x$\end{tabular}}
          {\begin{tabular}{c}gebrochen rational:\\ $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$\end{tabular}}
        \makebox[\widthof{$y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$}]{rational}
      }
      {}
      {}
      {\begin{tabular}{c}irrational\\ $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$\end{tabular}}
    \makebox[\widthof{$y=f(x)=\sin(x)$}]{algebraisch}
  }
  {}
  {}
  {\begin{tabular}{c}tranzendent\\ $y=f(x)=\sin x$\end{tabular}}
elemantar

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

A first cut at this would be, using the `array` package:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{tabular}{M c} % ❶
    \left.
    \begin{array}{c C{1.0in}} % ❷
      \left.
      \begin{array}{c C{1.0in}} % ❸
        \left.
        \begin{tabular}{c} % ❹
          ganz rational. Polynom:\\
          $y=f(x)=x$\\[.4ex]
          gebrochen rational:\\
          $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
        \end{tabular}
        \right\}
        &
          rational\\
        &
          irrational:\break
          $y=f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
      \end{array}
      \right\}
      &
        alebraisch\\
      &
        transcendent:\break
        $y=f(x)=\sin x$
    \end{array}
    \right\}
    &
      elementar
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation}
```

The secret sauce here is mixing `tabular` and `array` based on whether we want to have a text `c`-column or not (you can use `tabular` anywhere you use `array`. The converse is not true) and defining a new column type `C` which gives us a centered `p`-style column.

But we miss out on how the text tucks under the brace and the `\arraycolsep` is a bit much. I was originally thinking that I would do some fancy footwork with new column types to add negative space here and take care of the latter by changing `\arraycolsep` and then I realized ‍♂️ that I could do both with the same command by setting `\arraycolsep` to a negative value since there's a large right brace at *every* column separation.

Putting

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{-5pt}
```

after `\begin{equation}`¹ *almost* solves it. The problem is that we get `\arraycolsep` at the *sides* of the `tabular` or `array` environment as well as between columns.² But remember that `@` in a column specification tells LaTeX not to insert the `\arraycolsep` so we can change some column specifications to be (use the circled numbers for reference of where to change):

```
    \begin{array}{c C{1.0in}@{}} % ❷
      \begin{array}{c C{1.0in}@{}} % ❸
        \begin{tabular}{c@{}} % ❹
```

There's doubtless fine-tuning that can be done, but this should be enough to enable further exploration.

---

1. I put it here so that it won't affect any other `tabular` or `array` environments in the document.
2. The `amsmath` matrix environment does manual spacing around its inner `array` to get rid of this. We take a different approach here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Don. I am always amazed a how much one can do with the tabular and array options in LaTeX. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `rcases` machinery of the `mathtools` package may amount to code overkill. A couple of nested `tabular` environments, along with suitably-placed `\left.` and `\right\}` statements, would appear to get the job oone.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\left.
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc}
  $\left.
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc}
    $\left.
      \begin{tabular}{@{}c}
        ganz rational, Polynom:\\
        $f(x)=x$ \\[12pt]
        gebrochen rational:\\
        $f(x)=1/x$ 
      \end{tabular} 
    \right\}$
    & rational \\
    \addlinespace
    & irrational: \\
    & $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
  \end{tabular}
  \right\}$
& algebraisch \\
\addlinespace
& transzendent:\\
& $f(x)=\sin x$
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\mbox{ elementar}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico. That is exactly what I was trying to do, but I had problems with the `\left.` and `\right\}` and the arrays / tabulars.